# SQL display date column as column header

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sample SQL query

```
select dispdate, name, pass 
from tbllog
```

which produces this result:

```
Date | Name | Pass 
------------------
0827 | abc  |  50  
0827 | abc1 | 100  
0828 | abc  |  80   
0828 | abc1 |  20
```

However, I would like the results to read

```
Name | 0827  | 0828
-------------------
abc  |  50   |  80
abc1 | 100   |  20
```

with the dates being the column names. There can be any number of names and dates in my query.

Comment: Search for "sql server dynamic pivot".

Comment: You should learn about PIVOT. Here is a useful link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Gordon how do I mark your comments as my answer?

Comment: My comments are not an answer and don't deserve to be treated as such.  Answer the question yourself with the appropriate link to one or more references that helped you.